# how to notify user when user has browser open?

Tags: javascript, jquery, notifications

You get notification for new answers and stuff in SO. (The red mark next to StackExchange at the top)

The notification mark appears even if user doesn't interact with the browser(no reloading).

How can I implement such a feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would research topics like WebSockets, long polling, SignalR, NodeJS for examples of implementations of similar features.

Ex: http://signalr.net/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology

Answer (score 0):

I think WebSockets is the real solution here. But, If you don't want to go so far, you can use a timer from client side to check if new notifications exist.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    startTimer = function() {
        window.setTimeout(checkNotifications, 15000);
    },

    checkNotifications = function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/notifications/check",            
            success: function(result) {
                //show red mark if notifications exist
                startTimer(); //start timer to check again 
            }
        });
    }

    startTimer();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're asking about Javascript, I would use some sort of database or XML document to store notifications and then just check for new notifications.

You can use PHP to call XML data using Jquery (AJAX) from a custom script like this: (I've yet to test this, but I hope someone finds it useful)

Example XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<notifications>
    <user>
        <id>673154978</id>
        <notes>
            <note>
                <id>98465321865</id>
                <date>1374112224</date>
                <userID>168948521</userID>
                <url>/question?q=894251&a=1364567891</url>
                <type>answer-question</type>
                <topic>Can you tell me some Lorem Ipsum?</topic>
                <content>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempus nisi ac arcu congue, a scelerisque tellus facilisis.</content>
            </note>
            <note>
                <date>1374112570</date>
                <userID>168982417</userID>
                <url>/question?q=894251&a=1364567987</url>
                <type>answer-question</type>
                <topic>Can you tell me some Lorem Ipsum?</topic>
                <content>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempus nisi ac arcu congue, a scelerisque tellus facilisis.</content>
            </note>
        </notes>
    </user>
</notifications>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

function getUserInfoByID($userID) { # For converting the ID to the username
    $foundUser = false; # Default false
    $users = simplexml_load_file('data/usersAndIDs.xml'); # Load this XML as SimpleXML object
    foreach($users as $userTag) { # Cycle through users
        if($userTag->userID = $userID) { # Does this match?
            $foundUsername = $userTag; # Ah, here's the username and the other info like last time active, list of seen notifications, etc.
            break; # Stop loop as we're now done
        }
    }
    return $foundUser; # Return the info. May be bool(false) or the username
}

if(isset($_POST['type']) && $_POST['type'] != '') { # Is this set?
    if($_POST['type'] == 'notifications') { # Is it "nofitioncations?"
        $notifications = simplexml_load_file('data/notifications.xml'); # Load this XML as SimpleXML object
        foreach($notifications as $users) { # Go through XML per "user" tag
            if($users->id == $_POST['userID']) { # Find whose notifications to return


                #Either just go straight to encoding for the Javascript to form, as seen below
                # echo json_encode($users->notes); # JSON encoding for the Javascript to read. Remove the pound symbol at the beginning of this line to use it and comment out or remove the rest of the script that creates this in the PHP


                # Or get it all into order now.

                $theUserInfo = getUserInfoByID($_POST['userID']); # Get all of the users info by the sent ID
                $userSeenNotes = json_decode($theUserInfo->seenNotes); # seenNotes tag in the user XML may contain an array in JSON format for easy storage like <seenNotes>["6816818618","61861681861","436881613","681898213","46848153"]</seenNotes>

                foreach($users->notes as $note) { # Cycle through notes


                    if(!in_array($note->id, $userSeeNotes)) { # Already been seen? If not, then continue. You may wish to also check if it was recent enough and then make it show up slightly darker to show that it's been seen already. Seen in this case means they followed the link. You'd want to write that to data/usersAndIDs.xml as I've used earlier in this script

                        $type = explode($note->type, '-'); # From "answer-question" to array('answer','question')

                        $answerersInfo = getUserByID($note->userID); # Get all of the answerer's info by the ID in data/notifications.xml

                        echo
                        '<div class="notification $type[0]">' . # This is the notification   --   Lines do not need the "' . (line break) '" stuff. I added that to add comments so that they're not part of the HTML
                            '<a class="note" href="http://yoursite.com' . $note->url . '">' . # Link all text to specific answer
                                '<span class="note-$type[1]">' . $note->topic . '</span>' . # Question topic. I would suggest cutting this off using a set width and height with "overflow: hidden;" in CSS
                                '<span class="note-$type[0]">' . $note->content . '"</span>' . # The reply answer. I also suggest cutting this off
                                '<span class="note-user">by ' . $answerersInfo->username . '</span>' . # Probably would appear very small just as a preview
                                '<span class="note-date">' . gmdate("r", $note->date) . '</span>' . # Date in GMT in this format: "Thu, 21 Dec 2000 16:01:07 +0200". Could also use date() 
                            '</a>
                        </div>';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Javascript: (adapting Leantraxxx's answer above for my PHP)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    startTimer = function() {
        window.setTimeout(checkNotifications, 15000); // 1000 * (seconds to wait)
    },

    checkNotifications = function() {
        $.post('notifications.php', { 'userID': '673154978', 'type': 'notifications' },
            function(data){
                $('div#notifications').append(data);
            }); // Use '}, "json");' if you're going to format the info from JSON here. As is, the PHP will format it the way I wanted to, but you can remove that and uncomment the part about JSON encoding (Line 23-ish)
            startTimer(); //start timer to check again 
        }

    startTimer();

});
```